# SF Marketing Cloud - Query Variable Table for value used in SQL function

Tags: marketing-cloud, sqlserver, sql

Salesforce Marketing Cloud queries do not allow variables or temporary tables according to the "SQL Support" section of this official documentation (http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

I have a data extension called Parameters_DE with fields Name and Value that stores constant values. I need to refer to this DE in queries.

Using transact-SQL, an example is:

```
DECLARE @number INT
SET @number = (SELECT Value FROM Parameters_DE WHERE Name='LIMIT')
SELECT *
FROM Products_DE
JOIN
Expiry_DE
ON
dateadd(day, @number, getdate()) < Expiry_DE.Best_Before
```

Is it possible to get the value for @number from Parameters_DE and use it in the dateadd() function without using temporary tables or variables?

Comment: Where are you writing this query? Is it the query activity ?

Comment: Yes, this is a query activity written in Email Studio

Comment: I don't think it is possible in Query Activity.